# Branch from a previous commit using Git

Tags: git, branch, commit, git-branch

If I have an `n` number of commits, how can I create a branch from the `n-3` commit?

Answer (score 3725, accepted):

Create the branch using a commit hash:

```
git branch branch_name <commit-hash>
```

Or by using a symbolic reference:

```
git branch branch_name HEAD~3
```

To checkout the branch while creating it, use:

```
git checkout -b branch_name <commit-hash or HEAD~3>
```

Comment: Git 1.8.2 let me use the short sha1 for the first form.

Comment: @MattFenwick Git will allow you to use shortened hashes everywhere a hash is allowed, as long as the shortened hash is ''unique'' in the repository. So if it didn’t work, try adding another character from the hash.

Comment: To push the new branch correctly to server.. needed this last step: `git push origin BRANCH_NAME`

Comment: to start a branch from `<sha1-of-commit>` run `git checkout -b <name-of-branch> <sha1-of-commit>` but if the branch already exists `git checkout -B <name-of-branch> <sha1-of-commit>`

Comment: Also: `git branch branchname HEAD^^^`

Comment: This also works with the more recent `switch` command using the create option: `git switch -c branchname <sha1-of-commit or HEAD~3>`

Comment: Even after pushing to the server with Gene Bo's `git push origin BRANCH_NAME`, git still tells me "fatal: The current branch TDD_2023-05-31 has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use `git push --set-upstream origin BRANCH_NAME`", which I did.

Comment: @mostafazh +1 that's what I'm looking for: `git checkout -B <branch-name> <commit-sha1>`

Answer (score 368):

To do this on github.com:

1. Go to your project.
2. Click on the "Commits".
3. Click on the **<>** ("Browse the repository at this point in the history") on the commit you want to branch from.
4. Click on the "tree: xxxxxx" up in the upper left. Just below the language statistics bar, you'll get the option to "Find or Create Branch" (just type in a new branch name there) [image: Branch from previous commit]

Comment: Despite the fact that this is Github not git, it was still immensely helpful!

Comment: Unfortunately it still shows changes from other commits, which I wanted to avoid, which is why I searched for this question

Answer (score 133):

The magic can be done by **git reset**.

1. Create a new branch and switch to it (so all of your latest commits are stored here)

   ```sh
   git checkout -b your_new_branch
   ```
2. Switch back to your previous working branch (assume it's master)

   ```sh
   git checkout master
   ```
3. Remove the latest x commits, keep master clean

   ```sh
   git reset --hard HEAD~x    # in your case, x = 3
   ```

From this moment on, all the latest x commits are only in the new branch, not in your previous working branch (master) any more.

Comment: This is what I was looking for since it removes the commits from the Master and makes it as though you had remembered to make the branch before those commits were made. Thanks.

Comment: Just don't forget that a `git reset --hard` is not a good idea if you already have pushed the commit to origin...

Comment: you can `git push --force ` if you had already pushed the branch before

Comment: But be really careful when using --force https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/force-with-lease/

Comment: CAUTION: Assuming "all the latest x commits are only in the new branch, not in your previous working branch (master) any more" is what you want. To people reading this: if you aren't *certain* that describes what you want, don't do this - it alters the master branch.

Comment: I don't understand the logic of this answer. The poster wants to create a new branch with code from the previous commit. This seems to create a branch from the current master, and then revert master to a previous commit. Am I wrong?

Comment: @andream. yes you got it right, but both your sentences are the same thing

Comment: @georgiecasery I think I don't understand what a HEAD is, but I thought the poster did not want to change the head of the master branch, (the code seems to revert the head of master to 3 commits before). 

In other words, if I git checkout master, do I see  HEAD or HEAD-3?

Comment: i.e.,do I lose any changes made in head-2, -1, 0?

Comment: @andream. no, you won't.  But the head-2, -1 will be in your_new_branch instead of master.

Comment: ok but if so I don't think that's what the poster wanted. He wants the new branch to start from head-3

Comment: `git push --force` is only appropriate when working without collaborators.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion. There should be no need for `git push --force` if this is done properly. Note in step #2, "previous WORKING branch". If you're doing what the OP is trying to do, the `git reset --hard HEAD~x` resets the local-only changes that you want to be only on your new branch. It can dip into remote changes if you're careless, and that would require a `git push --force`, but that is not what the OP is doing here

Comment: @andream., that's correct, but still no contradiction. This solution takes the top 3 commits from curent or `master` or whatever and *moves* them to a new branch. So the new branch *does* start from 3 commits back, but those commits are then dropped from the branch where they were originally committed, so the original or `master` is back to where it was. This fits a scenario where you start making commits and then realise you didn't create a new branch.

Answer (score 99):

If you are not sure which commit you want to branch from in advance you can check commits out and examine their code (see source, compile, test) by

```
git checkout <sha1-of-commit>
```

once you find the commit you want to branch from you can do that from within the commit (i.e. without going back to the master first) just by creating a branch in the usual way:

```
git checkout -b <branch_name>
```

Comment: I /think/ this answer may have been rendered wrong by time.
`git checkout -b`  and `git branch` seem to always checkout the head for me, not the current detached position, unless the hash is specified as an extra argument.
see `git switch -c newbranchname`

Comment: That's what I meant with the angular brackets: you need to specify the hash.

Comment: But you need to specify the hash in the (second) `branch` or `checkout -b` command, not just the <branch_name>. The first command you show is actually irrelevant if you already knew the hash.

Comment: Sorry, I see my previous comment doesn't make sense. Still, I don't understand what you mean by "detached position". How is it different from HEAD? Did you mean to say "main" or "master" in your original comment, instead of "head"?

Comment: May be poor terminology - I mean the current checked out hash/position is NOT the HEAD.
When I checkout to a specific changelist I see this message "You are in a detached state" or similar. 
Hence "detached position".

Comment: I'm asking, because the message for me is "You are in 'detached HEAD' state." Furthermore, HEAD tracks whatever I last checked out. What version of git are you using? Mine is 2.38.1. Also, see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References#ref_the_ref

Comment: Anyway. Do you see my issue with your second git statement or not?

Comment: Not really. That's why I was trying to clarify. "It works for me." ™ More specifically, the branching point is whatever commit I checked out with the first command. It is also where HEAD moves, after the first command. If I understand you correctly, you're saying HEAD does not move for you there, which is the thing that's confusing for me. From the documentation, I understand that it should.

Answer (score 77):

Simply run:

```
git checkout -b branch-name <commit>
```

For example:

```
git checkout -b import/january-2019 1d0fa4fa9ea961182114b63976482e634a8067b8
```

The `checkout` command with the parameter `-b` will create a new branch ***and*** it will switch you over to it.

Comment: is it possible to create a branch based on the SHA commit of a feature branch that was deleted via a pull request? Or do I have to branch from the commit of the pull request on master?

Comment: run `git fetch` & `git branch` command on your project's folder using the terminal, then check if the feature branch exists, if this is case then yes, of course you wont be able to create a branch from deleted branches, you could also revert a branch deletion in case the branch is gone

Answer (score 37):

```
git checkout -b <branch-name> <sha1-of-commit>
```

Comment: How is this different from "`git branch branchname <sha1-of-commit>`" (from the accepted answer)?

Comment: I don't know. I think they are equivalent. I always use `git checkout -b` to create a new branch.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7987711/3590629
git branch... creates the branch but leaves you on current branch.
git checkout -b... creates the branch and switches you to it.

Answer (score 27):

This creates the branch with one command:

```
git push origin <sha1-of-commit>:refs/heads/<branch-name>
```

I prefer this way better than the ones published above, because it creates the branch immediately (does not require an extra push command afterwards).

Comment: I didn't even know this is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

This is what I did:

```
C:\Users\[path]\build>git checkout -b responsivenavigation 8a75b001096536b3216022484af3026aa9c7bb5b
Switched to a new branch 'responsivenavigation'

C:\Users\jaimemontoya\[path]\app>git branch
  master
* responsivenavigation
```

In this case, `8a75b001096536b3216022484af3026aa9c7bb5b` was and old commit belonging to the `master` branch.

Answer (score 16):

Using **Sourcetree** | The easiest way.

- First, checkout the branch that you want to take the specific commit to make a new branch.
- Then look at the toolbar, select Repository > Branch ... the shortcut is Command + Shift + B.
- And select the specific commit you want to take.
  And give a new branch name then create a branch!

[image]

Answer (score 14):

A great related question is:  How the heck do you figure this out using the `--help` option of Git?  Let's try this:

```
git branch --help
```

We see this output:

```
NAME
       git-branch - List, create, or delete branches

SYNOPSIS
       git branch [--color[=<when>] | --no-color] [-r | -a]
               [--list] [-v [--abbrev=<length> | --no-abbrev]]
               [--column[=<options>] | --no-column]
               [(--merged | --no-merged | --contains) [<commit>]] [--sort=<key>]
               [--points-at <object>] [<pattern>...]
       git branch [--set-upstream | --track | --no-track] [-l] [-f] <branchname> [<start-point>]
       git branch (--set-upstream-to=<upstream> | -u <upstream>) [<branchname>]
       git branch --unset-upstream [<branchname>]
       git branch (-m | -M) [<oldbranch>] <newbranch>
       git branch (-d | -D) [-r] <branchname>...
       git branch --edit-description [<branchname>]
```

Gobbledegook.

Search through the subsequent text for the word "commit".  We find this:

```
   <start-point>
       The new branch head will point to this commit. It may be given as a branch name, a
       commit-id, or a tag. If this option is omitted, the current HEAD will be used instead.
```

We're getting somewhere!

Now, focus on this line of the gobbledegook:

```
git branch [--set-upstream | --track | --no-track] [-l] [-f] <branchname> [<start-point>]
```

Condense that to this:

```
git branch <branchname> [<start-point>]
```

And done.

Answer (score 14):

No one mentioned [git switch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) yet?

You can do:

`git checkout <commit-hash>`

Or by using a symbolic reference:

`git checkout HEAD~3`

And then:

`git switch -c my-new-feature-branch`

Comment: I suspect because some of the answers here are >10 years old.
I /think/ some of them have been rendered wrong by time as well.
`git checkout -b`  and `git branch` seem to always checkout the head for me, not the current detached position.

Comment: This is the modern answer since Git 2.23 which came out Aug 2019.

Answer (score 9):

A quick way to do it on your GitHub repository would be as followed:

- Find the specific commit from your branch
- Beside the SHA id, click on 'Browse the repository at this point in the history'
- Here you can create a new branch from this commit

  [image]

Comment: This is actually outdated

Comment: The question is not about github.

Comment: Duplicative of this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18137009/1175496

Answer (score 4):

To do this in Eclipse:

- Go to "Git Repository Exploring" Perspective.
- Expand "Tags" and choose the commit from which you want to create branch.
- Right click on the commit and choose "Create Branch".
- Provide a branch name.

It will create a local branch for you. Then whenever you push your changes, your branch will be pushed to the remote server.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Select Commit]

For Git GUI users you can visualize all the history (if necessary) and then right click on the commit you wish to branch from and enter the branch name.

[image: Enter Branch name]

[image: Visualize all the history]

Comment: This will work only if user using any UI based OS like Windows & MAC

Comment: That's right. My reply specifically starts with the words "For Git GUI users ...". I have not given a reply which will work for everyone - that is already done. I have given an alternative method which might be easier for a lot of people. I think the reason my reply is disliked is because its not a solution for everyone, but that already exists with a couple of thousand upvotes. However that doesn't make my reply wrong "For Git GUI users!". CREATE NEW BRANCH is there in the GUI. I doubt I am the only person in the world using it!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do it like so:

```
git branch new_branch_name `git log -n 1 --skip 3 --format=%H`
```

Where you must enter the skip value. 0 is the latest, 1 is the previous, 2 is the commit before that, etc.

Comment: Why not just use `HEAD~1` (where 1 specifies 1 commit back)?

Comment: Your way is covered by the selected answer, and works fine. Mine is a different way than the selected answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in Stash.

1. Click the commit
2. On the right top of the screen click "Tag this commit"
3. Then you can create the new branch from the tag you just created.

Comment: What GUI is this? GitHub?

Comment: Atlassian Stash

Answer (score 3):

***Go to a particular commit of a Git repository***

Sometimes when working on a Git repository you want to go back to a specific commit (revision) to have a snapshot of your project at a specific time. To do that all you need it the SHA-1 hash of the commit which you can easily find checking the log with the command:

```
git log --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline
```

which will give you a compact list of all the commits and the short version of the [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hash.

Now that you know the hash of the commit you want to go to you can use one of the following two commands:

```
git checkout HASH
```

or

```
git reset --hard HASH
```

***checkout***

`git checkout <commit> <paths>`

Tells git to replace the current state of paths with their state in the given commit. Paths can be files or directories.

If no branch is given, Git assumes the HEAD commit.

```
git checkout <path> // Restores <path> from your last commit. It is a 'filesystem-undo'.
```

If no path is given, Git moves `HEAD` to the given commit (thereby changing the commit you're sitting and working on).

```
git checkout branch // Means switching branches.
```

***reset***

```
git reset <commit> // Resets the current pointer to the given commit.
```

If you are on a branch (you should usually be), `HEAD` and this branch are moved to commit.

If you are in detached `HEAD` state, Git reset does only move `HEAD`. **To reset a branch, first check it out.**

If you wanted to know more about the difference between git reset and Git checkout I would recommend to read [the official Git blog](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

Comment: thank you for your answer, FYI: This : `git log --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline
` can be abbreviated to `git log --oneline`

Answer (score 2):

### With [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements) (version currently used: 3.1.3)

1. Open the **History** in Sourcetree

   [image: Find history in Sourcetree]
2. It will list all the commits in the main window
3. Right-click on the desired commit and click on the `Branch...` option.
4. Give a name for the branch in the new window and click `Create branch`.
5. The new branch (local to your system) will come on the left side along with the other existing branches, which you can push to the origin to get it to the repository, that way it becomes available to other users.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why people enjoy making things more complicated. Here is a simple one-liner to

```
git checkout <commit_id>        # Gives a snapshot of the repository at this commit
git switch -c <new_branch_name> # Creates a new branch from that commit
```

Answer (score 1):

With [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/), display the history pane and right click on the commit you want. Then choose the menu item "Create branch from commit".

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a command-line based solution, you can ignore my answer. 
I am gonna suggest you to use [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/). It's an extraordinary git UI client. It shows the Git tree on the homepage. You can just look at them and know what is going on with the project. Just select a specific commit, right-click on it and select the option 'Create a branch here'. It will give you a text box to enter the branch name. Enter branch name, select 'OK' and you are set. It's really very easy to use.

Answer (score -1):

I used [Git Gui](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui/) (which comes with Git for Windows).

1. On the menu bar, open the **Branch** menu and select **Create...**
2. Specify the name for the new branch in the **Branch Name** section
3. Select **Revision Expression:** in the **Start Revision** section and enter the commit ID (I just used the 8 digit ID from Visual Studio and it worked)

[image: Create New Branch dialog window]

Answer (score -2):

If you use [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements) that is pretty straightforward.

- Right click the commit from where you need to create a new branch
- Click on 'branch'
- Type name of new branch in the dialog appeared and click 'create branch'