# branch and checkout using a single command

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-checkout

Creating and using a new branch involves two commands:

```
$ git branch new_branch_name
$ git checkout new_branch_name
```

I tend to forget the latter, which can be annoying. Is there a way to do this using a single command? Perhaps using an alias, or something similar? I know I could write a shell function, but that seems a bit much work for such a simple and common task.

Bazaar does support this to some degree using the `bzr branch --switch` notation.

Comment: Was about to downvote for lack of research effort, but then I realized you were answering your own question.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Git introduced `switch` in version 2.23 to handle changing of branches specifically and avoid the use of `checkout` which can be confusing by the sheer amount of operations it can do.

Among other possibilites,

```
git switch <branch>  # to switch to an existing branch
git switch -c <new_branch>  # to create a new branch and switch to it
```

Answer (score 158):

While writing the question, and finding [What is the difference between "git branch" and "git checkout -b"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7987687/1468366) in the list of similar questions, I found the answer myself:

```
$ git checkout -b new_branch_name
```

I guess I was reading the man page for the wrong command, I was expecting this as part of the `branch` command, not for `checkout`. Quoting the man page for `checkout`:

> Specifying `-b` causes a new branch to be created as if `git-branch(1)` were called and then checked out.

Just what I was looking for.

Comment: [“And how should I create a branch?” “Use `git checkout`.”](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2013/04/git-koans/#one-thing-well)

Comment: 13ren: Updated link: https://stevelosh.com/blog/2013/04/git-koans/#s2-one-thing-well

Comment: Thanks. I always forget that its not branch but checkout command :-( And skimming the git branch --help in vain.

Answer (score 15):

There are two oneliners for this in git.

1. `git checkout -b new_branch_name`
2. `git switch -c new_branch_name`

Under the hood, both do the same thing:

```bash
git branch new_branch_name
git checkout new_branch_name
```

Answer (score 0):

What I generally use is the `git checkout -b MY_NEW_BRANCH_NAME origin/master`

This `checkout` the new branch you recently create, with the `-b` , and connect the branch with the `origin/master` branch, so later you don't need to set remote tracking `--set-upstream` (if you already set it for your local master branch).