# revert the git last commit and save it in a different branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit, git-reset

Is there a way to rollback the last commit and put it into a separate branch for later testing? I did some changes which I don't want to entirely throw away, I just want to keep them aside in a different branch for further testing.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this - branch away from the current branch and create a new branch to preserve the commit, checkout back to the original branch, and then rollback the commit in the original branch.

So from your current branch, (lets call it `current`), create and checkout a new branch `separate`

```
git checkout -b separate
```

This will [create a new branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7987687/1860929) `separate` which will have the new commit. Now go back to the original branch

```
git checkout current
```

On this branch, you can now [rollback the last commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/927358/1860929)

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

If you later want to access that older commit, you have to do a `git checkout separate` and the commit should be available in that branch.

Comment: anash0l the approach works well, locally, but when I tried to push to github it didn't go through.. any idea what am missing?

Comment: @MoJ.Mughrabi Had you already pushed to github (before doing these operations)? Could someone else have pulled in the changes?

Comment: @anash0l yeah i did, but i have deployment scripts which tries to pull and they don't see the new revert action. As I used "push -f" to get the changes through to github

Comment: @MoJ.Mughrabi okay, do you want to push branch `separate` as well? In that case, do `git push origin separate`. That should create a new branch `separate` on github as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in two steps and without switching between branches. Here we go.

1. Create a new branch from the current branch, to set aside your current state:

   ```
   git branch feature_maybe
   ```
2. Revert the last commit in the current branch:

   ```
   git reset --hard HEAD^
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - check out a new branch using `git checkout -b <new branch name>`, switch to the original branch using `git checkout <original branch name>`, then do `git reset --hard HEAD~1` to move the original branch back a commit. (As always when moving branches around, it's safest to visualise what you're doing step-by-step using a program like `gitk`.)