# Using "git checkout -b" to create new branch off of public repository

Tags: git

I am trying to use "git checkout -b" to create a new branch off of a public repository. I was reading something about this at [What is the difference between "git branch" and "git checkout -b"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987687/what-is-the-difference-between-git-branch-and-git-checkout-b). Tuong Le provided this solution:

```
git checkout -b [NEW_BRANCH] [FROM_BRANCH]
```

He added that `if there's no FROM_BRANCH, git will use the current branch`.

I am trying to figure out what to use in `[FROM_BRANCH]`.

When from my local computer I use `git remote -v`, I get this:

```
origin  ssh://[username]@[domain]/~[username]/public_html/public.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://[username]@[domain]/~[username]/public_html/public.git (push)
```

I use SSH to login to the server where I have that public repository and I do this:

```
# git remote -v
origin  /home/[Unix user]/public_html/app (fetch)
origin  /home/[Unix user]/public_html/app (push)
# pwd
/home/[Unix user]/public_html/[path to source code]
# git branch
  D
  newheader
  responsivenavigation
  bluesidebar
* master
  reports
```

I know that if I simply use `git checkout -b mynewbranch` without specifying `[FROM_BRANCH]` it is going to create a new branch off of `master` because `master` is the current branch. That is not what I want. I want to create a new branch off of a branch called `mynewbranch` that I have in this public repository: `/home/[username]/public_html/public.git`. That is a remote repository that when I use `git branch -a` in my local computer, I see it as `remotes/origin/mynewbranch`. Thank you.

UPDATE 1: I could easily use this from my local computer: `git checkout -b mynewbranch remotes/origin/mynewbranch`. But the thing is that I am not trying to do this from my local computer. I am using SSH to access the server, and from the server, which is where I have this `remotes/origin/mynewbranch`, I want to create a new branch off of this `remotes/origin/mynewbranch`. When I go to the server and use `git branch -a`, I do not see this `remotes/origin/mynewbranch`. Where does it reside? How can I create a new branch off of `remotes/origin/mynewbranch` from the server where this `remotes/origin/mynewbranch` branch resides? The problem is that when I use SSH to log in to the server and use `git branch -a`, I do not see this `remotes/origin/mynewbranch` branch. I was expecting to see it.

UPDATE 2: The syntax is:

```
git checkout -b [NEW_BRANCH] [FROM_BRANCH]
```

I am trying to use this:

```
git checkout -b mynewbranch origin/mynewbranch
```

I get this error:

```
error: pathspec 'mynewbranch' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'origin/mynewbranch' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

UPDATE 3: From my local computer I do this:

```
git branch -a
```

One of the lines of the results is:

```
remotes/origin/mynewbranch
```

Perfect so far. This means that when from my local computer I used `git push origin mynewbranch`, the command did its job to push the code from my local computer to the public repository. That is why I see this public repository on the server: `remotes/origin/mynewbranch`. All I want to do now is to checkout on the server the code that I just pushed to this public repository: `remotes/origin/mynewbranch`. How do I do that? When I log in to the server where I have the public repository, I use SSH and then I try `git branch -a`. I cannot see `remotes/origin/mynewbranch`. I want to checkout that branch from the public repository, not from my local computer. How do I do that?

Comment: Use `origin/mynewbranch` as `[FROM_BRANCH]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between origin/branch\_name and branch\_name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125162/difference-between-origin-branch-name-and-branch-name)

Comment: @mkrieger1 I am using `# git checkout -b mynewbranch origin/mynewbranch` and I get this result: `fatal: 'origin/testimonials' is not a commit and a branch 'testimonials' cannot be created from it`. Apparently it is not recognizing `origin`.

Comment: Another post that possibly answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch

Comment: Are you using that command on the server? You need to use it on your local computer.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I am trying to use `git checkout -b [NEW_BRANCH] [FROM_BRANCH]` on the server, yes, in order to create a new branch on the server. But you are saying that I need to use it on my local computer.

Comment: Didn't you say that the branch already exists on the server? I guess then I don't understand what your situation is and what you are trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch)

Comment: @mkrieger1 The branch already exists on the server because I did this from my local computer: `git push origin mynewbranch`. I can confirm that the branch already exists on the server because when from my local computer I use `git branch -a`, I see this as one of the branches: `remotes/origin/mynewbranch`. But when on the server I use `git branch`, I do not see the `mynewbranch` listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to use the following from the server where I have the public repository:

```
# git pull /home/[username]/public_html/public.git mynewbranch
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a branch called `mynewbranch` that starts at (and tracks) an existing remote branch locally bookmarked as `origin/mynewbranch`, usually you can just say

```
git checkout mynewbranch
```

As long as `mynewbranch` doesn't exist and `origin` is the only repository for which you have a remote tracking ref named `(repo)/mynewbranch`, this will create the local branch and associate it with the tracking ref.

Answer (score 0):

When you are starting to work on an existing remote branch, you need to simply use the --track flag while checking out the branch. 
eg.

```
$ git checkout --track origin/feature
Branch feature set up to track remote branch feature from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'feature'
```