# Difference between "checkout" and "checkout -b" when remote exists?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

If I have a remote branch, I can locally do `git checkout MyRemoteBranch` and it will work fine. By work fine I mean it will create a local branch called MyRemoteBranch and switch to it, and this local will track the remote.

In this case, when do I have to pass the `-b` parameter? What is the difference between the below when the remote does exist:

```
git checkout MyRemoteBranch
```

Vs

```
git checkout -b MyRemoteBranch
```

Comment: https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987687/what-is-the-difference-between-git-branch-and-git-checkout-b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Caleb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52709862/1256452) is correct (and I've upvoted it) but here it is in more precise notation:

- `git checkout -b name` tries to create a new branch name *`name`*, using the current (HEAD) commit as the hash ID for the new branch.  This fails if the branch name already exists.
- `git checkout name` tries to check out an existing branch using the name *`name`*.

  - If that fails because *`name`* does not exist, it goes on to a second step, which Git documentation sometimes calls the "DWIM" mode: *Do What I Mean*.
  - The DWIM step checks all of your remote-tracking names: `origin/name`, `upstream/name` if you have a remote named *`upstream`*, and so on.  If *exactly one* matches, it performs the equivalent of:

    `git checkout -b name remote-tracking-name`

    which as you can see has one more argument than the original `-b` option.
- `git checkout -b name commit-specifier`—which you can invoke manually if you like, but is invoked for you by the DWIM mode—tries to create a new branch name *`name`*, using the given *`commit-specifier`* as the hash ID for the new branch.  This fails if the name exists *or* if you can't `git checkout` that particular commit hash ID right now. (See [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452) for more about when you can or cannot switch to another commit.)
- For completeness, we should also mention `git checkout --track remote-tracking name`, e.g., `git checkout --track upstream/develop`.  This looks up the remote-tracking name, then uses it to create a new (local) branch using the same name: in this case it would create a new branch `develop`, as if you'd run `git checkout -b develop upstream/develop`.  It's useful if you have *no* `develop` right now, but *do* have *both* `origin/develop` *and* `upstream/develop`.  The DWIM mode won't work because `git checkout develop` doesn't know whether to use `origin/develop` or `upstream/develop`.

Answer (score 6):

> In this case, when do I have to pass the -b parameter? What is the difference between the below when the remote does exist

The difference is that if you pass the `-b` flag, `git` creates a **new** branch with the name you give and based on the branch you were in when you created that branch. Without the flag, `git` will look for an existing branch, including one in any remote repos that you're tracking, and switch to one of those if if finds one.

So, let's say: 1) you're currently in your own branch called `foo`; 2) you've got a remote called `upstream`; and 3) that remote has a branch called `bar`. If you say:

```
git checkout bar
```

then you'll switch to a local copy of the `foo` branch on `upstream` (assuming your repo already knows about `foo` because you've recently done a `git fetch`). In other words, if you do:

```
git diff upstream/bar
```

then `git` will report no differences.

But, if you give the `-b` flag:

```
git checkout -b bar
```

then `git` will create a *new* branch that happens to also be named `bar`, but that will have the same content as the `foo` branch that you were just in. In other words:

```
git diff upstream/bar
```

will report the differences between `upstream`'s `bar` branch and your local `bar` branch (which, again, got its content from your `foo` branch).

It's easy to try this yourself. Just pick two existing remote branches that don't exist locally, say `upstream/branch1` and `upstream/branch2` on your remote that you know have some differences. Verify that there are differences with `git diff upstream/branch1 upstream/branch2`. Now checkout the first branch without the `-b` flag:

```
 git checkout branch1
```

Now you should have a local branch called `branch1`. Again, check that this matches the upstream version: `git diff upstream/branch1 branch1`. There should be no differences. Next, try creating a `branch2` using the `-b` flag:

```
 git checkout -b branch2
```

Now you should have a local `branch2`, but it should match what's in `branch1` and also `upstream/branch1`. Verify:

```
 git diff upstream/branch1 branch2      # should be no diffs
 git diff upstream/branch2 branch2      # should be like diffing branch1 and upstream/branch2
```

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout MyRemoteBranch` is when is already this branch in the remote repository

`git checkout -b MyRemoteBranch` with this -b you create a new branch locally no matter if is not in the remote

Comment: If remote exists, and we pass `-b`, does passing `-b` detach the branch? Means it won't have its upstream set. My Q is what is the diff when remote exists.

Comment: The git command will not let you create a new one so you have to do the checkout without the -b or you will get an erro

Answer (score 0):

There is a plenty of difference between those two commands.
when you use

```
git checkout myRemoteBrench
```

It only switch your branch if the branch is already existing.

But when you use

```
git checkout -b myRemoteBranch
```

First it check whether the mentioned branch is existing, if not it creates a new branch with the given name and switch to it.