# Create Branch from an Older Commit

Tags: git, branch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [branch from a previous commit using git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816715/branch-from-a-previous-commit-using-git)

Can we create a branch from a previous commit? From the example below, can I create a branch from `f70c700` (we're already at `fabdd09` at this point):

```
$ git log --oneline --graph
*   fabdd09 Merge branch 'mybranch'
|\  
| * bd35011 Edit from mybranch
* | f70c700 Edit from master
|/  
* a2ff940 Initial submission.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as easy as:

```
git branch my-new-branch f70c700
```

... or if you want to create the branch and switch to it in one command, you can do:

```
git checkout -b my-new-branch f70c700
```