# Github - need help on giving pull request

Tags: github

I forked a project, did changes(C1) and gave pull request which is still in pending. After a week i want to give another pull request with changes(C2).

Meanwhile, upstream (where i forked from) gets lot of changes. So i want to sync my master with upstream, and need to give pull request with changes C2 alone (no need to add changes c1, because i gave separate pull request for this already).

> Note: I don't have any branches. I committed C1 in my master and gave
>   pull request. Did changes C2. But this time, i don't where to commit C2 and how to give pull
>   request without adding C1.

Comment: Did the detailed steps I have added in [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17447104/6309) helped you to make a pull request for `C2` without including `C1`?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. But the way you explained make sense. I think you got enormous experience in this area. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have done C2 in its own branch, all you need to do is:

- update your master with upstream/master
- rebase your C2 branch on top of upstream/master
- make your pull request from C2 branch.

[image]

Note that if you rebase C1 branch on top of upstream/master, your existing pull request will automatically be updated!

See also "[How to do a Github pull request?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309)".

---

The [OP user10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1280221/user10) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446004/github-need-help-on-giving-pull-request#comment25457420_17447104):

> I committed `C1` in my master and gave pull request.
>   I did changes `C2`, and don't know where to commit and how to give pull request without adding `C1`.
>   This is my problem.

So you have:

```
y--y--y--y  (origin/master)
\
 x--C1--C2  (master)
```

First, don't do any rebase on top of `origin/master`, which would trigger an update on your existing pull request (but this time, with `C1` and `C2` from your rebased `master`, as I mention in my **[pull request tips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309)**, in the second point)

Make sure [C2 is in own branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2816728/6309):

```
git checkout master
git branch bC2
git reset --hard master C2~
git tag C2base master
```

If `C2` is composed of several successive commits, replace `C2~` by the first commit of the `C2` series, followed by a '`~`'.
This assume `C2` commits follow `C1` commits.

Make sure you don't have any work in progress (not committed): the '`reset --hard`' would erase those.

Note that the tag `C2base` reference the commit just before `C2`. We will need it below.

```
y--y--y--y   (origin/master)
\
 x--C1       (master)
    ^ \
    |  --C2  (bC2)
 (C2base)
```

Then a `git pull --rebase origin` will replay your master on top `origin/master`.

```
y--y--y--y          (origin/master)
\         \
 |         x'--C1'  (master)
 |
 x--C1    
    ^ \
    |  --C2  (bC2)
 (C2base)
```

Note how `C1` gets duplicated here, and is still referenced through the `bC2` branch.

Finally, make sure your `bC2` branch is done on top of `origin/master` has well:

```
git rebase --onto origin/master C2~ bC2
git tag -d baseC2
```

Which gives you:

```
           C2'      (bC2)
          /
y--y--y--y          (origin/master)
          \
           x'--C1'  (master)
```

(The old `C1` commit is no longer referenced by anything, so it disappears in the [reflog](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog), which can be used to [revert improper rebase, for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/135614/6309))

And you now can do your pull request from the `bC2` branch, which contains only `C2` commits!

Comment: I have no branches. I committed C1 in my master and gave pull request. I did changes C2, and don't know where to commit and how to give pull request without adding C1. This is my problem.

Comment: @user10 Sure. I have edited the answer to include the detailed sequence of commands needed in your case.

Comment: What tool did you use to generate those graphs?

Comment: @ChrisHeald err... simple manual ascii art (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art) ;)

Comment: Sorry, no, the graph up top. Or was that just something you already had handy?

Comment: @ChrisHeald it comes from a blog post from Jimmy Bogard on LostTechies: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/04/02/working-with-forks-on-github-or-codeplex/. I don't know what he used, though.

Answer (score 0):

before every PR you should be up to date with the master branch. it means that the order of PRs isn't significant for you. finally master branch (and possible new fork) will contain all changes.