# How to clone a remote fork after moving to new computer

Tags: git, git-clone

We have a remote master on GitHub at: `git@github.com:mainproject/mainproject.git` and I created a fork from it by clicking on the fork button, so that it looks like this: 
`git@github.com:myuser/mainproject.git`

I'm not allowed to synchronize my remote fork into that remote master (git@github.com:mainproject/mainproject.git), I'm only allowed to synchronize the remote master into my remote fork.

In the past, I had used the following commands once because I got told so:

```
git remote add -t master upstream git@github.com:mainproject/mainproject.git
git fetch -a
git merge --ff-only upstream/master
git push origin HEAD
```

The command `git branch -a` showed there then:

```
  master
  tutorial/test1
* tutorial/test2
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/tutorial/test1
  remotes/origin/tutorial/test2
  remotes/upstream/master
```

The command `git remote -v` showed there then:

```
origin   git@github.com:myuser/mainproject.git (fetch)
origin   git@github.com:myuser/mainproject.git (push)
upstream    git@github.com:mainproject/mainproject.git (fetch)
upstream    git@github.com:mainproject/mainproject.git (push)
```

And the .git/config file showed there then:

```
[core]
  repositoryformatversion = 0
  filemode = false
  bare = false
  logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  url = git@github.com:myuser/mainproject.git
[branch "master"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "upstream"]
  url = git@github.com:mainproject/mainproject.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/upstream/master
```

I had pushed my last changes with the command `git push origin tutorial/test2` to my remote fork, because `tutorial/test2` was and is my current branch, I'm working on it. That is how it has worked on my old computer.

On a new computer with freshly installed operating system I would like to continue to work on my project in my remote fork. I want to continue where I left off on the old computer and have already pushed the last changes from my old computer to my remote fork. I would like to continue to work in the branch `tutorial/test2`.

Do I only have to repeat all the Git commands, which are listed above, on the new computer again after a call of the command `git clone git@github.com:myuser/mainproject.git`?

Or would it be wrong and I would have to go another way now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I only have to repeat all the git commands, which are listed above, on the new computer again after a call of the command git clone git@github.com:myuser/mainproject.git?

That sounds about right.

Your new computer will get a new clone of your fork, which knows nothing about upstream remote, so you need to add that remote again.
This is what I described in "[Forking vs. Branching in GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3611349/6309)".

Note that I prefer working on a dedicated branch that I:

- rebase on top of `upstream/master`
- push to my fork.

That way, the pull request is done from that branch instead of `master`.
Each push would  update the pull request automatically.
Each changes are isolated in that branch (you don't have to check if they come from `upstream/master` or your `master`, since you are not working in `master`)

See also:

- "[Github - need help on giving pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17447104/6309)"
- "[couple of tips on Pull Request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309)"