# Git - Create a new remote branch out of an old commit

Tags: git, branch, commit

I'm using the following Git command in order to create a new remote branch:

```
git push origin origin:refs/heads/new_branch_name
```

I wish that the new branch will start from an old commit,

How can I do that? (I've tried some different methods, though failed)

Thank you.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
git checkout -b new_branch_name
git reset --hard <old_commit_id>
git push origin new_branch_name
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is a one-liner:

```
git push origin <id-of-commit>:refs/heads/<name-of-remote-branch>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it is more to the point of the question. And perfect in the sense that you do not have to check out the branch.

Answer (score 2):

if you want create a new branch from a specific commit, execute command `git log` or `gitk`, copy the id and execute command `git checkout ID COMMIT`, then commit and push. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816715/branch-from-a-previous-commit-using-git) can help you.

Comment: This question is mainly about creating new *remote* branch, but thanks anyway.

Comment: When you execute command ``git checkout ID COMMIT``, and then execute ``git checkout -b NEW BRANCH`` and execute push, new remote branch is created with code from ID COMMIT selected

Comment: @Taru The title, though, does not imply the `remote` part. Thanks for the question, in any case.