# How to branch from n-4 commits, and set n-4 as master?

Tags: git

I should have created a branch called `develop` n-4 commits ago, can I go back and set n-4 to be `master` and create a new branch from that point which includes the last n-4 commits?

I'm using [GitExtensions](https://gitextensions.github.io/) on Windows but happy to do from commandline if easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Branch from a previous commit using git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816715/branch-from-a-previous-commit-using-git)

Comment: No because I want to include the last n-4 commits in my branch and put master back to n-4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using following commands:

```
git checkout -b develop HEAD
git branch -f master HEAD~4
```

First one creates a new branch `develop`. Next just reset the branch `master`

Answer (score 0):

Stash all your changes, then:

```
 git branch develop
 git reset --hard HEAD~4
```