# Starting a new branch from a specific commit (and erase older ones)

Tags: git, github, version-control, commit

I am quite new to Git and I joined a company as an intern. I (stupidly) started all of my branches by pulling our staging environment. So when I compare on github, there are like a hundred commits, and then mines.
The issue is that there are waaaaay too many conflicts to push these branches on master.

That's why I'm desperately trying to find a way to start a branch from a specific commit without having the previous (i.e. the ones coming from the staging pull) ones, only the latest. 
For example :

```
git pull origin staging
[I did my stuff]
git commit -m "some stuff done"
[some other stuff]
git commit -m "other stuff done"]
```

I would like to go back to the commit "some stuff done" without having everything that the "pull origin staging" has done and also keeping "other stuff done".

I have already checked and tried the solutions on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816715/branch-from-a-previous-commit-using-git) but it still keeps the old commits.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a situation where you need `git cherry-pick`.

I would go back to master, where I understand you want your branch to start from, create a fresh branch, then cherry pick your commits.

- `git checkout master`
- `git checkout -b my_branch`
- `git cherry-pick` *commit1*
- `git cherry-pick` *commit2*

where *commit1* and *commit2* are the sha1 hashes for your first and second commits.

If the master branch is where you were when you did the two commits, you'll need modify the above commands a bit.

- create the new branch from the specific starting point you want:

  - `git checkout -b my_branch origin/master` or some other sha1 hash instead of `origin/master`.
- do the two cherry picks
- Fix master by resetting it back to origin/master:

  - `git checkout master`
  - `git reset --hard origin/master`.
- Go back to your branch to keep working:

  - `git checkout my_branch`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks it kind of worked, I still had a ton of conflits to take care of but it did the trick. I just wanted to add that `git reflog show --no-abbrev my-branch` was really helpful to see which commits were mines in each branch