# merge submodule till specific version with my older version submodule

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

I want to to merge  a submodule till specific commit with the older version sub module which i made commits on and don't want it to get deleted

Comment: Make a new branch from the newer branch, and reset to the commit you want to revert to, and then merge on the older branch

Comment: ok , I think that will work
thank you very much

Comment: There is a problem that when I pull to the branch it will merge with the old commits

Comment: Before I revert back to the point want

Comment: You can try this. This should definitely work in your case and without causing problems on merging. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2816728/5316422

Comment: once you have the new branch, merge to that branch from the submodule branch that you want.. and you will have exactly what you want. then later when you want to merge it all, just merge this branch into main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked best form me was

```
git fetch

   git checkout FETCHED_HEAD

    git checkout -b newbranch commitSHA1
    git checkout master
    git merge newbranch
```

Comment: Since your problem has been solved, you can mark the answer.