# How to save current code as a Git branch and reinstate earlier code?

Tags: git

While changing my code I have made several commits to my Git repo (and pushing each set of changes). As I now need to reinstate an earlier commit to make unrelated changes, I want to save the current code as a branch that I can later return to.

Here is what I want to do. Let's take the commit I want to reinstate as repo_v6. Since then I have made various changes (repo_v6, repo_v7 etc), so that I now have repo_v9:

1. repo_v6    <--- I want to go back to this
2. make changes, commit as repo_v7
3. make changes, commit as repo_v8
4. make changes, commit as repo_v9   <--- my current tip

I want to go back to repo_v6, but keep the changes I made between repo_v6 and repo_v9 in a safe place in case I want to use them later.

My repo contains just the master branch, as - not expecting to need branches - I did not create a branch earlier. Though I have read several help topics, I cannot see how to go back - and put aside but keep the changes - without having cretaed a branch earlier. Having never created branches in the past, I do not know what to do. Please can you advise?

I am the only developer who uses the repo, so do not need to consider changes made by others.

Comment: did you try `git branch myNewBranchName` and then `git checkout myNewBranchName` ? then you can go back to `master` by `git checkout master`

Comment: Please read this: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches#:~:text=A%20branch%20represents%20an%20independent%20line%20of%20development.&text=The%20git%20branch%20command%20lets,checkout%20and%20git%20merge%20commands.

Comment: @Ahmad Thanks, but I am still not clear what to do.I have edited my question to make clearer what I want to do. I suspect the challenge is that I did not create a branch earlier. I now realise I need to go back to an earlier point, but want to preserve my changes for possible later use, then go back to an earlier commit without the changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move the most recent commit(s) to a new branch with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git) Assuming you don't want to keep your commits v6 to v9 on the current branch and just branch out from an older point like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816715/branch-from-a-previous-commit-using-git)

Comment: Just to be clear: you want newBranchName to point to repo_v9, and you want master to essentially the same code as repo_v6, correct?

Comment: @John, yes, exactly. I want newBranchName to point to repo_v9, and I want master to essentially the same code as repo_v6.

Comment: @finch See my answer below.  This is another way (via rewriting history) but I don't like to introduce that to folks new to Git because it's easy to lose your work and can be difficult getting it back when you don't know where to look. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to create a branch from a specific commit is via `git branch`.  In this case, you have two options.  You can use:

```
git branch newBranchName repo_v9
```

where you explicitly create a branch from repo_v9, or since it's the current tip of master, and that's what you have checked out, you can drop the repo_v9 and run:

```
git branch newBranchName
```

In this case, it'll infer the commit (`HEAD`), which points to the tip of master, since that's the current branch you are on.

From there you really have two options: 1) forcibly roll back the commits as though they never happened, 2) essentially revert the commits introduced since repo_v6.  Since 1) involves rewriting history and is not conducive to working with a team, and since master tends to be the development branch of choice for teams, we'll look at option 2).

#### Revert the individual commits

You can use the `git revert` command to "undo" commits.  In this case, you can revert the whole series of them with:

```
git revert repo_v7..master
```

This will undo all the commits starting with repo_v7 going to the tip of master.  This isn't a great option for lots of commits because it's create a new commit for every commit that is being reverted.  And it will pop up the editor for each of them.  You can avoid that with the `--no-edit` option, but there is another way too.

#### Revert the tree

When many commits are involved, this is the option I use.  You simply checkout the files from the version you want, and then commit the result:

```
git checkout repo_v6 .
git commit
```

The `git checkout` will make your working tree look like the contents at repo_v6.  Everything will be staged and ready to go as the index is updated to match as well.  Then you just commit the result.

Comment: Thanks. I did what you suggested, but find that HEAD is detached. What do you suggest? I did `git branch newBranchName`, then `git checkout <commitNumber>`. I then realised I missed out the ending period, so redid this as `git checkout <commitNumber> .`. But `git status` and now `git commit` show the HEAD detached.

Comment: @finch Right, so `git checkout <commitNumber>` switches the tree away from the branch and checks out that specific commit, putting you in a detached head state.  You'll want to be on the branch you want to roll back (say master) using `git checkout`: `git checkout master`.  Then run `git checkout <commitNumber> .`.  This latter form says "make the current working tree (for the current branch) look as it did in `<commitNumber>`".  At that point, you should be able to commit again.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks John, your explanation seems to have fixed it. HEAD is no longer detached.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 (optional):  If you have any uncommitted changes, stash them

```
git stash
```

Step 2:  Checkout the commit you want to go back to

```
git checkout repo_v6
```

Now do what it is you need to do with this version. Note that you are in a detached-head state (not on a branch). If you need to make new commits on top of this one (and not the tip of master), you will need to make a new branch here. `git checkout -b new_branch` When you are done:

Step 3:  Checkout master again

```
git checkout master
```

Step 4 (optional): If you stored a stash. restore it

```
git stash pop
```