# In Git, how to create a branch from the previous commit, and remove new commits from the master?

Tags: git

I realized that I had to create a branch first, but already did 2 commits. Okay, I found this post [Branch from a previous commit using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816715/branch-from-a-previous-commit-using-git) and created a new branch from a prev-prev commit using this command:

```
git checkout -b branch-name commit-id
git push origin branch-name
```

But when I looked back in GitHub I saw the master still has 2 last commits (that I wanted them to be only in a branch).

What should I do to get rid of them in the master but still keep them in the branch?

UPD
Found this solution.

1. Reverted to the previous commit `git reset --hard commit`
2. Pushed with force git push `--force origin master`

Comment: Master is already a branch which was created when you initialized git in your project I guess. As far as I know you are allways committing to a branch.

Comment: reverting commits on any branch is a common task. Move that commits to another branch could be tedious. Are you open to a non-elegant way? The elegant way is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git

Comment: @JRichardsz Hah I'm open to any way. I already found some way (see the update), wonder if your's is different or not. Thanks!

Comment: Watch out for the word "revert" in Git, which usually refers to the `git revert` command, not the `git reset` command. Revert as an English-language verb tends to mean more what `git reset` *does*, which means Git kind of assigned the wrong verb to the action (Mercurial uses `backout` where Git uses `revert`, which is a point in favor of Mercurial). Anyway, your solution (reset and force-push) is the right one for your case, it's just that this isn't *called* "reverting" in Git.

Comment: @torek Thanks for explaining, I didn't know that!

Comment: with your approach, just the master is update. What about the 2 commits? Didn't you need them in another branch?

Comment: @JRichardsz It's already there (see the beginning of my post) when I did the branching from the commit, they went to that branch.

Answer (score 1):

"Reverting" is not the right term, but what you did was effective:

```
git switch master
git reset --hard <past_commit>
```

Or, shorter, using [`git switch -C`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt--Cltnew-branchgt)

```
git switch -C master <past_commit>
```

Then:

```
git push --force
```

Assuming you are the only one working on that repository, that will reset the remote (GitHub) branch to what you want.

Comment: `git branch -f master thatcommit` skips the worktree churn of the switch/hard reset.

Comment: @jthill I agree. I have edited the answer to propose the alternative `git  switch -C`, which does include a `git branch -t`/`git switch` combo.