# How can I merge just the first commit of a pull request?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

My Github repository has received a pull request consisting of several commits. I only want to accept the first of these. Is there any way I can do this without asking the PR author to change their PR?

The PR was sent a long time ago and I've been unable to reach the author. I realise that I could just create a new commit myself, but I'd prefer to have the original commit author's name on the commit.

Comment: Make a new branch from the first commit, and merge it.

Comment: @matt How can I do that? I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816715/branch-from-a-previous-commit-using-git) but couldn't see how to handle that the commit is in a pull request.

Comment: Why does the pull request make a difference? A commit is a commit.

Comment: You cannot do this with the GitHub interface. It's easy to do with command-line Git though; see [phd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71173667/1256452).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd prefer to have the original commit author's name on the commit.

Nice and polite!

The first approach: create a commit and artificially assign it to a different author using [`git commit --author=<author>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---authorltauthorgt). You can even change author's date to the date of the commit at GH: [`--date=<date>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---dateltdategt).

The second approach is: fetch the PR from GH to a local branch and merge/cherry-pick one commit from the branch:

```
git fetch origin pull/$ID/head:pr-$ID # fetch the PR into branch pr-$ID
git log pr-$ID # view commits and find the one
git merge $COMMIT_ID
```

PS. Next time please use [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fetch+pull+request+locally).