# How to temporarily remove commit/commits and get it back afterwards

Tags: git, github

Here is an example that explains the scenario that I'm facing -
I have a feature branch Branch-A. It has got a commit SHA-1000.This is followed by multiple new commits.Now I create a new branch called Branch-B from Branch-A.

The commit SHA-1000 is reverted in Branch-A and In Branch-B new changes had been introduced.

Finally when the Branch-B is merged back with Branch-A, the code of SHA-1000 will not be there in the resultant code but I want it back.

I understand that I can always revert the commit with which I had removed the commit SHA-1000. But it not possible for me to anticipate such a scenario and keep tract of changes. So how is these kind of scenarios handled in software development ?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816715/branch-from-a-previous-commit-using-git. You can start a new branch from a previous commit and work from there, it won't have the commits after the base commit.

Comment: I have edited my original question now . Actually the commit SHA-1000 is not the final commit in Branch-A.. So I will not be able to create a branch from that commit. @vinkomlacic

Answer (score 1):

1. *All* commits in Git are snapshot + metadata.
2. `git merge` works by comparing the *merge base* to the two *tip commits*—that is, running two separate `git diff` operations—and *combining the changes*.
3. The merge base (normally<sup>1</sup> one specific commit) is found automatically based on the *best common commit* reachable from both branch tip commits.

These are all you need to know to solve your problem.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you build a complex graph and make some bad decisions, sometimes there is more than one best common commit, in which case the merge base is the result of merging the merge bases, unless you choose `-s resolve` as a merge strategy.

---

#### Your scenario

> I have a feature branch Branch-A. It has got a commit SHA-1000.This is followed by multiple new commits.Now I create a new branch called Branch-B from Branch-A.
>
> The commit SHA-1000 is reverted in Branch-A and In Branch-B new changes had been introduced.

Let's draw this:

```
...--o--∆--*--∇--o   <-- branch-A
            \
             F--o--o--o   <-- branch-B
```

where `∆` represents your "SHA-1000" commit.

> ... When the Branch-B is merged back with Branch-A, the code of SHA-1000 will not be there in the resultant code but I want it back.

This happens because the `git diff` from commit `*` to the tip of `branch-A` says to include the change from `∇` (i.e., revert the "then-bad" commit) while the change from `*` to the tip of `branch-B` says nothing about those lines of those files.

> I understand that I can always revert the commit with which I had removed the commit SHA-1000 [after merging].  But [I don't want to have to remember to do that].

What you need, then, is to *update the merge base*.  If the merge base were commit `∇` or later, you could cherry-pick commit `∆` into your `branch-B`:

```
...--o--∆--*--∇--o   <-- branch-A
               \
                o--o--o--o--∆'  <-- branch-B
```

Alas, no *existing* commit can be changed: commit `F`, the first commit that's exclusively on `branch-B`, *always* points to commit `*`.  So you have two options:

- You can *rebase* `branch-B`.  Doing so means *copying every commit that's currently exclusively on `branch-B`, starting with `F`, to some new-and-improved commit.  The "improvement" will be that the updated `branch-B` begins at commit `∇`.  This actually *damages* `branch-B`, so you'd probably want to put commit `∆'`—the cherry-pick of commit `∆`—in right away.  This might also have other drawbacks, e.g., picking up too many intermediate commits.
- You can *merge* `branch-A`, or any commit at or after commit `∇`, *into* `branch-B`.

This has the advantage of not having to "rewrite history", with all that that entails.  It otherwise has the same disadvantages: you might pick up too much work.  But it's still a good option.  Here's what that might look like:

```
...--o--∆--*-----------∇--o   <-- branch-A
            \           \
             F--o--o--o--M--∆'  <-- branch-B
```

You'd simply run:

```
git switch branch-B
git merge <hash of ∇>
[fix any conflicts if needed and commit]
git cherry-pick <hash of ∆>
```

Now the *future* merge base of the tip commits of `branch-A` and `branch-B` is commit `∇`.  The diff from `∇` to tip-of-branch-A commit *does not* do anything to the lines affected by `∆`, while the diff from `∇` to the tip-of-branch-B commit *puts back* commit `∆` via the cherry-pick.

(You can rebase or merge further down the line on `branch-A` if you like.  Commit `∇` is *necessary;* any additional commits are optional.)

Again, that's all there is to know.  You either rebase or merge so that the future merge base starts where you need it to.  If that can't work because it brings in "too much" from `branch-A`, you're stuck with having to remember to un-revert later, or reverting parts of `branch-A` *on* `branch-B` and then repeating this process in the other direction so that `branch-A` will not lose *its* work.

The *mechanics* of doing this are a pain.  The *theory* is simple though.