# How to rollback and make new branch from rollback point

Tags: git

I have git project like this below

```
% git --log

commit 39b6b1d894d0788fdfc09947e1a5f88bf962b142 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: whitebear man <whitebear@whitebearnoMacBook-Air.local>
Date:   Wed Nov 9 15:29:13 2022 +0900

    all

commit 2656df9fb80b5085b4e7a50032712b13e3c407c9
Author: whitebear man <whitebear@whitebearnoMacBook-Air.local>
Date:   Thu Oct 13 13:48:36 2022 +0900

    all

commit d72472d00c649fdc04805d10c856d729e114a014
Author: whitebear man <whitebear@whitebearnoMacBook-Air.local>
Date:   Wed Oct 12 18:23:28 2022 +0900

    all

commit 0878cd86de3a939e8c99e33676abcfe1cfd14daa
Author: whitebear man <whitebear@whitebearnoMacBook-Air.local>
Date:   Tue Oct 11 11:38:58 2022 +0900

    all

commit 21c78ba8cfb811e1ad7dfb035ef5236e619f5d53
Author: whitebear man <whitebear@whitebearnoMacBook-Air.local>
Date:   Mon Oct 10 15:55:48 2022 +0900

    all

commit 9568b4b53fd14febc1ed100efcc6d412d0668471
Author: whitebear man <whitebear@whitebearnoMacBook-Air.local>
Date:   Mon Oct 10 15:37:27 2022 +0900

    all
```

Now I want to roll back commit `21c78ba8cfb811e1ad7dfb035ef5236e619f5d53` and make new branch.
However I want to keep the latest commit `39b6b1d894d0788fdfc09947e1a5f88bf962b142` as master.

I should rollback and make new branch?

or make new branch and rollback??

Comment: The Git tag really just is a helpdesk tag, right... Can't believe my eyes when a 10K rep asks such a question and a 500K and 25K rep user answer it. Is you guys' search that broken? Have you tried anything? Are you looking for a branch, and/or an interactieve rebase? Hard reset? Cherrypick perhaps? But you've asked over a thousand questions, you should know how this site works by now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Branch from a previous commit using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816715/branch-from-a-previous-commit-using-git)

Comment: `I want to roll back commit 21c78ba8cfb811e1ad7dfb035ef5236e619f5d53` roll back _to_ or revert? Since the commits you want and do not want are not sequencial, what do you want to do with the ones in between? Edit: Wat? How is that answer the one that answers what you asked? unclear question, -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just create a new branch from the `21c78ba8` commit:

```
git branch new_branch 21c78ba8
```

Answer (score 1):

@Tim's answer is a good point *if* you don't really want to rollback. If, however, you **really** want/need to *revert* what was done in 39b6b1d894d0788fdfc09947e1a5f88bf962b142, this is the simplest way to do it:

```
git revert 39b6b1d894
```

Comment: Thank you very much, revert/reset also I need to learn.